# How to retrieving specific records from SQlite (Need Query)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on apps in which I need retrieve specific records from one position to another. I have  table `Track_Detail` with 20 records.

How to retrieve records from **1 to 10** in one list and **11 to 20** in another list?

[image]

Here my source code:

retrieve record from `Track` table in list view

```
public List<CatSetGet> getMainListRecords() {
        List<CatSetGet> list = new ArrayList<CatSetGet>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TRACK;
        // like limit what query I needed here

        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return list;
    }


       db.openDataBase();
        mainlist= db.getMainListRecords();
        azAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(Main.this,
                new int[] { R.layout.common_list_item }, mainlist);
        lv.setAdapter(azAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: what reason for negative comment ?????

Comment: Negative votes is because you didn't show what you've tried so far. Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: yes of course see image like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use limit query.

**Example of  query:**

```
  SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE mColoumnID >= 1 AND mColoumnID <= 10;
```

Comment: thanks done. its work for me 
SELECT * FROM TRACK  WHERE  _id >= 1 AND _id <= 10;